# How can I parse a Hadoop table which is in json format. I want to format it in Hadoop only

Tags: sql, hadoop, hue

I have seen other posts on this platform but none of them completely answers my problem.
I have the below data in a table in Hue editor/hadoop. Can this parsing possible here or do I need to switch to hive? And can you share a code that would lead me to expected outcome shown below? Thanks, I'm an amateur while working with JSON data hence need this help.

Current values (one column with multiple key value pairs which should be separated in multiple columns as shown in expected outcome)

```
[{"testername":"john","testerno":"1234","city":"mumbai","date":"2019-12-11 00:09:25"}]
```

etc.

Expected outcome (table with left value as header and right value as header's value in multiple columns):

```
Testername Testerno
---------- -------
john       1234
```

Comment: Follow this https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/analyzing-twitter-feeds-using-hive-7e074025f295

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705858/using-json-serde-in-hive-tables
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe